# MemoryCache expiration takes longer than set up

Tags: c#, caching, memorycache

I am defining a custom `MemoryCache` instance in my code:

```cs
var cacheConfig = new NameValueCollection()
{
     {"CacheMemoryLimitMegabytes", "1"},
     {"PollingInterval", TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000).ToString()},
};
_memoryCache = new MemoryCache("EventCache", cacheConfig);
```

I am then adding items to the cache in another function:

```cs
_cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMilliseconds(1000);
_memoryCache.Set(e.Name, e, _cacheItemPolicy);
```

Given the constraint, I am assuming that items should expire after one second. If I set breakpoints in the code, it seems that the expiration works correctly. However, if I run the code without breakpoints, expiration can take anywhere between 10-13 seconds.

What might be causing this behavior?

**UPDATE 1**: Tried setting `SlidingExpiration` for the same interval, but the eviction delay persists.

Comment: I [can't seem to reproduce the issue](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GneDP1)

Comment: @Xerillio I can still repro this behavior locally, even after a restart. Interestingly enough, on a tangential conversation I learned that `PollingInterval` is really about how frequently the cache updates its stats rather than poll for item removal.